# How to suggest Flutter Mobile app on clicking flutter web app url?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, url, flutter-web

How to succeed When user tap on Flutter web url we should suggest whether open in Chrome or Flutter installed app?

Comment: You can do that using dynamic links feature provided by Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a native application selection dialog, then you should enable [deep linking](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) for your application.

This will result with an app chooser dialog on Android when user opens a URL which mobile application has registered as deep link or a "Open in application X" banner in Safari for iOS

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter , I have used [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package and followed document to succeed